# Implement Angular range slider using months

Tags: html, css, angular, slider

I'm implementing a range slider by months using ngx-slider.

I want the value to be 1-12 and the display legend to be January-December.

I achieve it using the code below.

```
export class AppComponent {
  minValue: number = 3;
  maxValue: number = 9;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 1,
    ceil: 12,
    translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
      switch (label) {
        case LabelType.Low:
          return "<b>March</b>";
        case LabelType.High:
          return "<b>October</b>";
        default:
          return "$" + value;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

And the result is this one:
[Link to the image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHPdk.png)

How can I remove the dollar sign of the start and end value?

Or do you have better recommendation npm library for range slider for months?

Answer (score 1):

Hello this time slider I used in the project
`https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/`
You can change the style using CSS,
Hope it can be adopted.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent {
  minValue: number = 3;
  maxValue: number = 9;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 1,
    ceil: 12,
    translate: (value: number, label: LabelType): string => {
      switch (label) {
        case LabelType.Low:
          return "<b>March</b>";
        case LabelType.High:
          return "<b>October</b>";
        default:
          return value;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

You should Remove Dollar ($) on last return statement